# Not able to handle browser refresh in angular 8

Tags: angular, browser, routes, refresh

i am using angular app in which in need to route to login page when user clicks browser refresh button.currently i am not using hashlocation strategy.When i am refreshing browser it is giving 404.this is my code :

```
this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
      console.log("running subscribe");
      if (ev instanceof NavigationStart && ev.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
        this.router.navigate(["/contact"] ,{replaceUrl:true});
      }
      else if(ev instanceof NavigationStart && ev.navigationTrigger === 'imperative')
      {
        if(!(this.router.navigated)){
if(ev.url=='/' || ev.url=='/contact')
{

}
else {
  this.router.navigate(["/contact"] ,{replaceUrl:true});
}
        }

      }
    })
```

It is working when i am using in my local machine but when i deploy this code in server it is still giving 404 on refresh.Need help for handling this issue.

Comment: you need to configure server to serve index.html in case of 404

Comment: is it possible without server dependency?

Comment: only, if you use hash strategy.

Comment: i used has strategy ,but it keeps on current route where refresh is applied..any idea why this code is working on local server machine but not on remote server

Comment: in case of server for every route it goes to server, because those routes are not on server it sends 404. in case of local node server, it knows how to handle those routes in case of ng serve

Comment: <web-app> 
    <error-page> 
        <error-code>404</error-code> 
        <location>/index.html</location> 
    </error-page> 
</web-app> i got this from SO it is askig to create web inf in src folder ..is it right approach..because at this time i dont have accesss to server ,i have to deliver it tommorow